# Что означает %s%13s\n и %7d%13d\n?

Tags: c

Всем привет, объясните пожалуйста, что это за запись в коде?

```
int n[10],i;
for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
    n[i] = 0;

printf("%s%13s\n","Element","Value");
for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
    printf("%7d%13d\n",i,n[i]);
```

Конкретно эти записи: `%s%13s\n`, `%7d%13d\n`?

Comment: Ничего интересного.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что именно и как именно выводить.

Например `%7d` - вывести переданное число в виде десятичного целого числа (`d` — *decimal*, десятичное) в 7 знакомест.

Подробнее читайте [описание функции `printf`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) и вообще о форматированном вводе-выводе в C — тут его не воспроизвести, слишком уж велика тема.